# python and quantlib - setting futures priority

Tags: python, quantlib

In setting up a curve using deposit rates and futures in python, is there a trigger which allows one to set when the futures start?

Looking for something similar to `DepoFuturesPriority` in the QuantLibXL version - which allows for `AllDepos`, `DeposBeforeFuturesStartDate`, `DeposBeforeFuturesStartDatePlusOne`, `DeposBeforeFuturesExpiryDate`?

Right now I am using

```
rate_helpers = depo_helpers[:4] + futures_helpers + swap_helpers
```

which basically uses the first 4 depos but until the expiry of the last depo not until the start of the first future.

Any help or suggestions appreciated